# Server.ScriptTimeout = 0 Not working

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, timeout, ado

I have an ASP Classic script that has to do a lot of things (admin only) including running a stored proc that takes 4 mins to execute.

However even though I have

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 0
```

Right at the top of the page it seems to ignore it - 2003 and 2012 servers.

I have tried indexing the proc as much as possible but its for a drop down of commonly searched for terms so I have to clean out all the hacks, sex spam and so on.

What I don't understand is why the Server.ScriptTimeout = 0 is being ignored.

The actual error is this and comes just

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0113'
>
> Script timed out
>
> /admin/restricted/fix.asp
>
> The maximum amount of time for a script to execute was exceeded. You
>   can change this limit by specifying a new value for the property
>   Server.ScriptTimeout or by changing the value in the IIS
>   administration tools.

It never used to do this and it should override the default set in IIS of 30 seconds.

I have ensured the command timeout of the proc is 0 so unlimited and it errors AFTER coming back from the proc.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0 is an invalid value for Server.ScriptTimeout for 2 reasons:

1. ASP pages have to have a timeout. They cannot run indefinitely.
2. ScriptTimeout can never be lower than the AspScriptTimeout set in IIS according to this statement from the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524831%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> For example, if NumSeconds is set to 10, and the metabase setting
>   contains the default value of 90 seconds, scripts will time out after
>   90 seconds.

The best way to work around this is to set Server.ScriptTimeout to a really high value.

Comment: But what happens if I don't want to give ALL pages in my system a massive timeout value. I only want certain pages to have a really high timeout. Setting the default in IIS to be really high will mean either I have to put Server.ScriptTimeout = 30 at the top of all my pages OR allow pages that could be hammered by BOTS / Hackers etc to run for a very long time which will cause problems.

Comment: I don't recommend changing the value in IIS. Only set Server.ScriptTimeout in the pages that need it.